# change DNS with php like as if editing hosts file?

Tags: php, apache, dns

I don't know how to phrase this better, mainly because I dont really know how DNS fully works.

Given a URL and an IP, is it possible to tell PHP to make all requests to that IP AS the given URL instead of the real DNS (Just as if you edited your hosts file locally)?

Comment: I don't follow.  Are you trying to do an fopen, curl, or similar?  If so, why not just use the IP address?

Comment: I am not sure I understand what you are asking, but have you looked at the host name http header?

Comment: Do you want to reroute requests?

Comment: I'm trying to make a tool for showing websites to clients when their nameservers are not setup. I am quite frustrated trying to explain how to edit hosts file

Comment: Like say i design their website on a new host, which I can only access via IP. i want to make a tool that accepts a domain and an IP and it 'emulates' the site in an iframe or better yet not in an iframe. and routes to that IP instead of the DNS ip

Comment: i think this is possible using shell script, And this shell script should be triggered using PHP function.

Comment: Sumant, do you have details how I might do this? I may be really silly here but couldnt I just send an http request to the IP, and in the header or something I tell it what domain it is for? or is that not how headers work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only solution I see is to run your own bind server, and tell your clients to use your bind server. You then have full control how a name is routed to a IP.

Comment: While this is certainly a solution, getting the client to use a alternate BIND server is probably just as problematic as having them modify their hosts files.

Comment: @MikeBrant the thought occurred to me to put that in my answer :) Or, as a alternative, make sure to have 99,999% uptime, so rerouting is not necessary :) Or .. to use a subdomain as test environment and demonstration environment

Comment: see my comments below in Mike's answer for a better explanation. I realize there are better ways, but these are for small personal clients, not company clients that use version control etc. I just want a simple solution when i setup a blog for someone on a new host and want to show them, without the much extra work of changing wordpress settings, re-registering paid ecommerce plugins, etc.

Comment: @Tallboy Why not use a subdomain for demonstration purposes? I have a lot of online demos for customers and my blog: see http://simplemvc.example.ganymedes.be/movies I can add those on the fly, without telling anyone and just providing the url

Comment: @jvberg, see last 2 comments in mike brant's answer

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately for your case, you are at the whims of your client.

If they type the IP address in their browser it will work, if they type the domain which has not been set up in DNS or in their hosts files, it will never reach a server that you control.

If you have designed you site correctly, it probably really shouldn't matter if they access it via domain name or IP address.

Comment: I probably wasn't clear. Say they have their old host at example.com, and their new host at example-new.com. I dont want to change their nameservers when their site is in development still, but I cant use IP because lots of my code depends on the domain being correct (I cant have 12.141.25.14/~username as the link to give them because then all the stylesheets break). The obvious thing is to tell them how to edit hosts file, which is a pain. I want to just have a very simple tool that only talks to the IP specified, just as if they edited their hosts file

Comment: Wordpress often has problems with this unless you change it in the settings page. But i use ecommerce software too often which needs to be 'registered' on a given url. it is a pain to change all this back and forth. it would definitely be worth my time to develop a quick tool (if its possible)

Comment: @Tallboy Why wouldn't you just create your own non-production domain name then?  If you have tools that use encrypted domain registration keys, then you should talk to those vendors about getting a key for dev/testing purposes.  In my experience, any decent vendor will give you this.  Also if the key is just tied to the domain (i.e. example.com) then using a subdomain like test.example.com should be suitable.

Comment: Without going into detail, i just really want to know if its possible or not. I know there are lots of ways to do things, but based on the requests I get most, this tool would make things very easy. I have someone right now with 2 hosts (theyre switching hosts). I have setup a site i designed on the new host, while their old host serves their old site. I want to show them the new site without changing tons of wordpress settings (I cant show them by IP, because the site breaks without changing all said settings).

Comment: So i cant update the nameservers when they havent seen their site yet, but I dont want to go in and change tons of settings back and forth if theres a way to just make a tool for them to view the site as if they edited their hosts file. From there, I just switch nameservers and its simple

Comment: @Tallboy The problem is, the tool would have to run on their machines, as without changing their host files, they will never hit your machine via some domain name.  Sure you could make some generic page that perhaps loads a site in an iframe of something, but that will only allow you to run a single page (as soon as the user starts to navigate in the iframe they will not be going to your script any more.  Your efforts are probably better put to use in getting your code to run better regardless of domain name used to access it.

Comment: @Tallboy As an example of how to make your code portable, you could perhaps try something like `$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] = 'your.domain.com';` at the very beginning of the script in order to trick the rest of the code into thinking you are running on a domain on which you are not actually running (this might work if you code uses this for domain keys, etc.).  Of course you would want to make sure all links on the website either don't use the host name, or your use the original IP address being used to access the site in the links.

Comment: Is it possible I can make my host act as a localhost, changing its own host file (or rather, adding the IP/username to the hostfile log), and just letting the user see what is the result?

Comment: PS. I've already fixed the site that made me think of this, now I'm trying to build it just for the sake of learning

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what apache does via .htacess or other configuration files. That is not a "change" to the DNS, but a way to manage every request as you want, even with a unique and generic .php file